# "Can't let qualified name" when using clojure.core.match

Tags: clojure, pattern-matching, clojure-core.match

I'm using [`clojure.core.match`](https://github.com/clojure/core.match) and seeing the following error:

> Can't let qualified name

My code resembles:

```
(match [msg-type]
       [MsgType/TYPE_1] (do-type-1-thing)
       [MsgType/TYPE_2] (do-type-2-thing))
```

Where `MsgType/TYPE_1` comes from a Java class:

```
public class MsgType {
    public static final String TYPE_1 = "1";
    public static final String TYPE_2 = "2";
}
```

What does this error mean, and how can I work around it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems [related to macro name binding](http://thinkrelevance.com/blog/2008/12/17/on-lisp-clojure-chapter-9), though I don't understand it deeply as I'm quite new to macros.

Originally I hoped using [`case`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/case) rather than `match` would prove a viable workaround:

```
(case msg-type
      MsgType/TYPE_1 (do-type-1-thing)
      MsgType/TYPE_2 (do-type-2-thing))
```

However the above doesn't work. `case` matches on the symbol `MsgType/TYPE_n`, not the evaluation of that symbol.

The best I've found so far is to convert the value coming in to a keyword and match that way:

```
(def type->keyword
     {MsgType/TYPE_1 :type-1
      MsgType/TYPE_2 :type-2})

(case (type->keyword msg-type)
      :type-1 (do-type-1-thing)
      :type-2 (do-type-2-thing))
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, pattern matching is not the right tool for comparing one variable with another. Patterns are supposed to be either literals such as `1` or `:a`, destructuring expressions or variables to be bound. So, for example, take this expression:

```
(let [a 1
      b 2]
  (match [2]
    [a] "It matched A"
    [b] "It matched B"))
```

You might expect it to yield "It matched B" since the variable `b` is equal to 2, but in fact it will bind the value 2 to a new variable named `a` and yield "It matched A".

I think you're looking for `condp =`. It's basically what you wish `case` would be.

```
(condp = msg-type
  MsgType/TYPE_1 (do-type-1-thing)
  MsgType/TYPE_2 (do-type-2-thing))
```